# Java / Android - equation for rounding up

Tags: java, android, math

I am building an android application. In my app, i need to be able to round up a double (42.42 for example) and also get how much i added to the original number in order to round it up. My current code isn't working, and its outputting 0.. Anyway to fix this?

My current code:

```
                float rounded = FloatMath.ceil(val);
                double getDecimal = (val - FloatMath.floor(val))*100;
                int noDecimal = (int) ((int) 100-getDecimal);
                float toadd = (noDecimal/100);
```

In my code the "rounded" variable is the simpel rounding, and "toadd" should be how much i added to it. For some reason toadd always comes back as 0. Any help?

Comment: Why you just do not use the BigDecimal and proper rouding, then just substract to gain the difference.

Answer (score 2):

You're dividing `noDecimal` by `100`.  Both are ints, and the result will always be an int.  In this case, it's an int between 0 and 1, which will always be truncated to 0.

What's wrong with just getting the number modulo 1 (`%1`), then getting the ceiling of the original number?

For completeness, you could simply change the last line to preserve the rest of the logic:

```
float toadd = noDecimal/100.0;
```

This changes the divisor to a float, and an `int` divided by a `float` yields a float.

Answer (score 1):

```
float toadd = (noDecimal/100);
```

This will give you 0, as you are dividing smaller integer by larger one..

Try to do like this: -

```
float toadd = (Float.valueOf(noDecimal)/100);
```

Also, you don't need to do **typecast twice** in the below code: -

```
int noDecimal = (int) ((int) 100-getDecimal);
```

Just, **outer cast** is enough: -

```
int noDecimal = (int) (100-getDecimal);
```

**Edit: -** Also, you might want to use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for this kind of problems..

Comment: Typecasting would work if you typecast to `float` or `double` *before* the division, not afterwards.

Comment: In relation to what are you telling this??

Comment: If you try running your proposed code, specifically `Float.valueOf(noDecimal/100)`, you'll find that value is 0.0, instead of the desired value.

Comment: @bdares. I haven't used that.. i have used `Float.valueOf(noDecimal) / 100`.. Note the bracket clearly in the code.

Comment: This is great, only problem is im using it in currency calculating, and this code outputs me a million digits. Is there any way to keep only the two last digits after the decimal point?

Comment: @arielschon12.. Use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for rounding the decimal digits..

Comment: Im not sure how to use this BigDecimal.. Can you post an example?

Comment: @arielschon12.. You can see http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/How_to_Use_Java_BigDecimal:_A_Tutorial very good tutorial about BigDecimal and its use..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something or not getting your intention right, but if you just want to know what you added, why don't just use the difference?

```
float rounded = FloatMath.ceil(val);

float toadd = rounded-val;
```

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, this might not always give the absolutely accurate result. But it's the general idea which can be used with `BigDecimal`, which offers a higher precision.

Comment: @RohitJain True. However, as he is only considering the first two digits after the decimal point anyway, I assumed it would be accurate enough for his purpose. But using `BigDecimal` as proposed is much better anyway.

Comment: This is great, but then toadd isn't only 2 digits after the decimal point. It is a dozen digits after the decimal point. Is there any way to limit that?

Comment: @arielschon12 I assume you want only two digits for a more compact output. In which case I would rather format the output than dump the rest of the digits. There are several ways to do this, with a `Formatter`for example. Take a look at `String.format`, you can easily create a string representation which only displays two digits after the decimal point and use this in your output. This way, you're not sacrificing any precision, in case you want to do more calculations with those numbers later on.